# Pull data from Redshift

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, ssis, amazon-redshift, excel-2013

We want to pull data from Redshift database into SQL Server. Currently, we are using SQL Workbench to analyze Redshift database. We referred the following link -

[Connect Your Cluster By using SQL Workbench](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/connecting-using-workbench.html)

Here we used - RedshiftJDBC41-1.1.17.1017 driver to connect. 
Now we want to push this data to DWH in SQL Server 2016.

So what is the best way to accomplish this? There is not much information on net on how to pull data from Redshift.

Can we have SSIS component or something in SSDT/SSIS2015 to load this data?

Or can we have a middle layer of any tool (any ETL tools or Excel) which will dump this Redshift data into CSV or something which will be readable in SSIS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Data from Amazon Redshift can be extracted and consequently loaded into almost any platform.

You have several options to move data from Redshift to SQL Server.

1. ETL Tool - You can use a commercial ETL tool. SSIS is a
   perfectly legitimate way to extract from Redshift and to land the
   data in SQL Server.
2. [S3 Files - You can unload the data from Redshift into S3 buckets and
   then use SSIS or bcp to copy data from buckets to your SQL Server](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_Unloading_tables.html)
3. [Local file system -- You can run the unload command to extract data 
   to local file system. You can have psql running locally in a server 
   inside of your network.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_UNLOAD.html)

[For information on how to connect SSIS and any other ETL or BI tool to Redshift please see this link.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/configuring-connections.html#connecting-drivers)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Please forget about excel. I just said because I wanted to quickly visualize that data. Regarding SSIS (SSIS 2015??), can you point me to url which will allow me to directly connect to Redshift?

Comment: You can get the info from the AWS Redshift console. It should look something like this: admin.xxxxxxxxxxa.us-east-1.redshift.amazonaws.com:5439. You can select "source" data type as PostgreSQL

Comment: As per my understanding , currently there is no native/direct way of connecting SSIS (2015) to Redshift. Unlesss you opt for third party ZappySys Transformation. Please confirm my understanding.

Comment: I am not an SSIS expert, but I am pretty sure it can read data from PostgreSQL data sources. I used it with Netezza several years ago.

Comment: Look at this: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2619/export-data-from-postgres-to-sql-server-using-ssis/ .. Remember as far as SSIS is concerned, Redshift can be treated as a PostgreSQL database

Comment: Thanks for all your inputs. I successfully connected to Redshift thru SSIS via ODBC Redshift 32-bit drivers.    FYI- AWS recommended not to use Postgre SQl drivers for JDBC or ODBC. Instead use the new Amazon Redshift–specific drivers JDBC/ODBC going forward. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/configuring-connections.html#connecting-drivers

Comment: Thank you Rameshar for sharing this link. I was not aware of it, and it proved very useful for me. The power of this site is that enables us to help each other. Very cool. THANK YOU!!

Answer (score -1):

Amazon Redshift provides ODBC Connectors which is not supported by any Sql Server BI Tools. MS BI stack only support OLE DB Providers and it is being provided by a third party vendor

I am trying to build SSAS cube sourcing data from Amazon RedShift.