# Migrating data from Amazon Redshift into SQL Server using SSIS package

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, ssis, amazon-redshift

I am trying to create a SSIS package to migrate data from Amazon into my SQL Server.

Is there a way to do it without installing additional plugins like ZappySYS or CozyRoc?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pull data from Redshift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39073343/pull-data-from-redshift)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using Redshift's `UNLOAD` command to export the data to S3. This would be run inside SSIS as a SQL command against the Redshift database.

You can then use the AWS CLI to download the exported flat files to your SSIS server for further processing and/or loading into SQL Server. This would be run inside SSIS as a CMD task.